# Load applets through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tomcat8

I have a web application hosted on Tomcat 8 serving applets. The HTML pages with applets work fine when i am accessing them over http. I have further configured SSL over nginx reverse proxy. Now when i try to access the same pages over https, i am getting a ClassNotFoundException for the applets. I tried googling but could not get a clear solution. What could be going wrong?

Edit:
I have applets embedded in Login.html using `<applet>` tag, which further is a part of angularjs web application hosted on Tomcat8 container. The applet is bundled in the jar file. 
The applet tag is HTML is as follows;

```
  <applet
        id="ABCobject"
        code="com.xxx.xxxxx.XXXXXApplet.class"
        archive="XXXXXApplet.jar"
    >
    </applet>
```

Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mxxx.xxxxxxx.in;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name mxxx.xxxxxxx.in;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/__xxxxxxx_in.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/wild-xxxxxxx-in.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
resolver 172.18.2.128 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";


access_log  /var/log/nginx/xxxx_access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/xxxx_error.log;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://mxxx.xxxxxxx.in:8080/xxx-web-app-xxx/;
   proxy_buffering off;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
   proxy_cookie_path /web-appxxx/ /;
}

}
```

The stack trace of the error is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.xxxx.XXXXApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you elucidate more: you have some applets as static content in a Tomcat container, how do you generate the pages? Through servlets, JSP or as static content? What is the exception stack trace you are getting? What is nginx reverse proxy configuration?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz: I have edited my question with more details. Please let me know if any more information is required. Thanks.

Comment: I would guess, that the browser could not download the applet. Did you try downloading it directly? How does your `<applet>` tag look like?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz: I have edited the question to include the applet tag. Yes the browser is not downloading the applet, when i access it over "https". It works fine when i access it over "http"

Comment: You can check in both `nginx` access and erro log and `Tomcat` access log if nginx is asking the right URI from Tomcat.

Comment: Not much of a help in logs!

Comment: You should see a request for `/XXXXXApplet.jar` in nginx access log followed by a request for `/xxx-web-app-xxx/XXXXXApplet.jar` in Tomcat's access log.